# error while writing with write_row using Spreadsheet::WriteExcel

Tags: perl, excel-formula, spreadsheet, cpan

I am using [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel-2.40/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm) to write data into excel. 
 for each row I have used **write_row().** 
When I try to write row having data (=) it throws an error saying:***Couldn't parse formula: =*** ,since excel consider it as formula.
I need to write data using array as one row only so is there any way out to do the same? 
 
Below is the code snippets:

```
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;
my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new("../tmp/op.xls");
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
my @data = ('1','1','=',"testdata");
$worksheet->write_row("A1", \@data);         
$workbook->close();
```

**Output:**

```
Couldn't parse formula: = at
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [DIAGNOSTICS](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#DIAGNOSTICS) section of  [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm) module document, it states that:

**Couldn't parse formula ...**

> There are a large number of warnings which relate to badly formed formulas and functions. See the ["FORMULAS AND FUNCTIONS IN EXCEL"](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/lib/Spreadsheet/WriteExcel.pm#FORMULAS_AND_FUNCTIONS_IN_EXCEL) section for suggestions on how to avoid these errors. You should also check the formula in Excel to ensure that it is valid.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i want something tht works with write_row() function and avoid formula errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want an equal sign in that cell and you can live with a little leading white space this will poke a '=' into that row without a formula error:

```
my @data = ('1','1', ' = ', "testdata");
```

Works in LibreOffice Calc too.

I'm curious how you intend using that = operator in the SS?  Can you build a dynamic Excel formula by dereferencing a cell with an operator in it?  Me not an Excel expert :-)